# How to customize the preview of Markdown in Pycharm?

Tags: html, css, pycharm, markdown

I am using the Pycharm. I want to write my notes in Markdown in Pycharm. And I have installed the plugin **Markdown support**. It works. However the font is ugly, so I want to customize it.

[image]

In settings, there is a place where the user can write his custom css.

[image]

My css code is as following. But it didn't work. And I tried to restart pycharm. It didn't work! The default.css will be at the end of this post. My OS is ubuntu 17.04 and the pycharm is community 17.02. The Noto Sans CJK SC has been installed and also supports my language (Chinese). Thanks a lot for your time and any advice.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Noto Sans CJK SC";
}

body {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -fx-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Noto Sans CJK SC";
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

a {
    background-color: transparent;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}

img {
    border: 0;
}

hr {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
}

pre {
    overflow: auto;
}

code,
kbd,
pre {
    font-family: "Roboto Mono";
    font-size: 1em;
}

input {
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

input {
    line-height: normal;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
th {
    padding: 0;
}

body * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
    font: 13px/1.4 "Noto Sans CJK SC";
}

a {
    color: #4078c0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

hr {
    height: 0;
    margin: 15px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

hr:before {
    display: table;
    content: "";
}

hr:after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 21px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 12px;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 11px;
}

blockquote {
    margin: 0;
}

ul,
ol {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

ol ol,
ul ol {
    list-style-type: lower-roman;
}

ul ul ol,
ul ol ol,
ol ul ol,
ol ol ol {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

dd {
    margin-left: 0;
}

code {
    font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
}

pre {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font: 12px "Roboto Mono", monospace;
}

.octicon {
    font: normal normal normal 16px/1 NotoSansCJKSC;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.octicon-link:before {
    content: '\f05c';
}

.markdown-body > *:first-child {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.markdown-body > *:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}


.anchor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}

.anchor:focus {
    outline: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

h1 .octicon-link,
h2 .octicon-link,
h3 .octicon-link,
h4 .octicon-link,
h5 .octicon-link,
h6 .octicon-link {
    display: none;
    color: #000;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

h1:hover .anchor,
h2:hover .anchor,
h3:hover .anchor,
h4:hover .anchor,
h5:hover .anchor,
h6:hover .anchor {
    padding-left: 8px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1:hover .anchor .octicon-link,
h2:hover .anchor .octicon-link,
h3:hover .anchor .octicon-link,
h4:hover .anchor .octicon-link,
h5:hover .anchor .octicon-link,
h6:hover .anchor .octicon-link {
    display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    font-size: 2.25em;
    line-height: 1.2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

h1 .anchor {
    line-height: 1;
}

h2 {
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    line-height: 1.225;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

h2 .anchor {
    line-height: 1;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.43;
}

h3 .anchor {
    line-height: 1.2;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

h4 .anchor {
    line-height: 1.2;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

h5 .anchor {
    line-height: 1.1;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #777;
}

h6 .anchor {
    line-height: 1.1;
}

p,
blockquote,
ul,
ol,
dl,
table,
pre {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

hr {
    height: 4px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 16px 0;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    border: 0 none;
}

ul,
ol {
    padding-left: 2em;
}

ul ul,
ul ol,
ol ol,
ol ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

li > p {
    margin-top: 16px;
}

dl {
    padding: 0;
}

dl dt {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 16px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}

dl dd {
    padding: 0 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

blockquote {
    padding: 0 15px;
    color: #777;
    border-left: 4px solid #ddd;
}

blockquote > :first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

blockquote > :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

table {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    word-break: normal;
    word-break: keep-all;
}

table th {
    font-weight: bold;
}

table th,
table td {
    padding: 6px 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table tr {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

code {
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 85%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

code:before,
code:after {
    letter-spacing: -0.2em;
    content: "\00a0";
}

pre > code {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    word-break: normal;
    white-space: pre;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.highlight {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.highlight pre,
pre {
    padding: 16px;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 85%;
    line-height: 1.45;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.highlight pre {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    word-break: normal;
}

pre {
    word-wrap: normal;
}

pre code {
    display: inline;
    max-width: initial;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: initial;
    line-height: inherit;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

pre code:before,
pre code:after {
    content: normal;
}

kbd {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 10px;
    color: #555;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-bottom-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #bbb;
}

.pl-c {
    color: #969896;
}

.pl-c1,
.pl-s .pl-v {
    color: #0086b3;
}

.pl-e,
.pl-en {
    color: #795da3;
}

.pl-s .pl-s1,
.pl-smi {
    color: #333;
}

.pl-ent {
    color: #63a35c;
}

.pl-k {
    color: #a71d5d;
}

.pl-pds,
.pl-s,
.pl-s .pl-pse .pl-s1,
.pl-sr,
.pl-sr .pl-cce,
.pl-sr .pl-sra,
.pl-sr .pl-sre {
    color: #183691;
}

.pl-v {
    color: #ed6a43;
}

.pl-id {
    color: #b52a1d;
}

.pl-ii {
    background-color: #b52a1d;
    color: #f8f8f8;
}

.pl-sr .pl-cce {
    color: #63a35c;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pl-ml {
    color: #693a17;
}

.pl-mh,
.pl-mh .pl-en,
.pl-ms {
    color: #1d3e81;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pl-mq {
    color: #008080;
}

.pl-mi {
    color: #333;
    font-style: italic;
}

.pl-mb {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pl-md {
    background-color: #ffecec;
    color: #bd2c00;
}

.pl-mi1 {
    background-color: #eaffea;
    color: #55a532;
}

.pl-mdr {
    color: #795da3;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pl-mo {
    color: #1d3e81;
}

kbd {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    font: 11px "Roboto Mono", monospace;
    line-height: 10px;
    color: #555;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-bottom-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #bbb;
}

.task-list-item {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.task-list-item + .task-list-item {
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.task-list-item input {
    margin: 0 0.35em 0.25em -0.6em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

:checked + .radio-label {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    border-color: #4078c0;
}

span.user-del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: inherit;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #f6f6f6;

    background-color: #959595;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 0px #ededed;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0px #ededed;

}
```

The default.css :

```
    /*
Adapted from https://github.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css

The MIT License (MIT)

Copyright (c) Sindre Sorhus <sindresorhus@gmail.com> (sindresorhus.com)

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.
*/

@font-face {
    font-family: octicons-anchor;
    src: url(data:font/woff;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff');
}

body {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -fx-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, freesans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

a {
    background-color: transparent;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}

img {
    border: 0;
}

hr {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
}

pre {
    overflow: auto;
}

code,
kbd,
pre {
    font-family: monospace, monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
}

input {
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

input {
    line-height: normal;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
th {
    padding: 0;
}

body * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
    font: 13px/1.4 Helvetica, arial, nimbussansl, liberationsans, freesans, clean, sans-serif, "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

a {
    color: #4078c0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

hr {
    height: 0;
    margin: 15px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

hr:before {
    display: table;
    content: "";
}

hr:after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 21px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 12px;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 11px;
}

blockquote {
    margin: 0;
}

ul,
ol {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

ol ol,
ul ol {
    list-style-type: lower-roman;
}

ul ul ol,
ul ol ol,
ol ul ol,
ol ol ol {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

dd {
    margin-left: 0;
}

code {
    font-family: Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
}

pre {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font: 12px Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Courier, monospace;
}

.octicon {
    font: normal normal normal 16px/1 octicons-anchor;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.octicon-link:before {
    content: '\f05c';
}

.markdown-body > *:first-child {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.markdown-body > *:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}


.anchor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}

.anchor:focus {
    outline: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

h1 .octicon-link,
h2 .octicon-link,
h3 .octicon-link,
h4 .octicon-link,
h5 .octicon-link,
h6 .octicon-link {
    display: none;
    color: #000;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

h1:hover .anchor,
h2:hover .anchor,
h3:hover .anchor,
h4:hover .anchor,
h5:hover .anchor,
h6:hover .anchor {
    padding-left: 8px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1:hover .anchor .octicon-link,
h2:hover .anchor .octicon-link,
h3:hover .anchor .octicon-link,
h4:hover .anchor .octicon-link,
h5:hover .anchor .octicon-link,
h6:hover .anchor .octicon-link {
    display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    font-size: 2.25em;
    line-height: 1.2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

h1 .anchor {
    line-height: 1;
}

h2 {
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    line-height: 1.225;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

h2 .anchor {
    line-height: 1;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.43;
}

h3 .anchor {
    line-height: 1.2;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

h4 .anchor {
    line-height: 1.2;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

h5 .anchor {
    line-height: 1.1;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #777;
}

h6 .anchor {
    line-height: 1.1;
}

p,
blockquote,
ul,
ol,
dl,
table,
pre {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

hr {
    height: 4px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 16px 0;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    border: 0 none;
}

ul,
ol {
    padding-left: 2em;
}

ul ul,
ul ol,
ol ol,
ol ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

li > p {
    margin-top: 16px;
}

dl {
    padding: 0;
}

dl dt {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 16px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}

dl dd {
    padding: 0 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

blockquote {
    padding: 0 15px;
    color: #777;
    border-left: 4px solid #ddd;
}

blockquote > :first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

blockquote > :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

table {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    word-break: normal;
    word-break: keep-all;
}

table th {
    font-weight: bold;
}

table th,
table td {
    padding: 6px 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table tr {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

code {
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 85%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

code:before,
code:after {
    letter-spacing: -0.2em;
    content: "\00a0";
}

pre > code {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    word-break: normal;
    white-space: pre;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.highlight {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.highlight pre,
pre {
    padding: 16px;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 85%;
    line-height: 1.45;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.highlight pre {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    word-break: normal;
}

pre {
    word-wrap: normal;
}

pre code {
    display: inline;
    max-width: initial;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: initial;
    line-height: inherit;
    word-wrap: normal;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

pre code:before,
pre code:after {
    content: normal;
}

kbd {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 10px;
    color: #555;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-bottom-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #bbb;
}

.pl-c {
    color: #969896;
}

.pl-c1,
.pl-s .pl-v {
    color: #0086b3;
}

.pl-e,
.pl-en {
    color: #795da3;
}

.pl-s .pl-s1,
.pl-smi {
    color: #333;
}

.pl-ent {
    color: #63a35c;
}

.pl-k {
    color: #a71d5d;
}

.pl-pds,
.pl-s,
.pl-s .pl-pse .pl-s1,
.pl-sr,
.pl-sr .pl-cce,
.pl-sr .pl-sra,
.pl-sr .pl-sre {
    color: #183691;
}

.pl-v {
    color: #ed6a43;
}

.pl-id {
    color: #b52a1d;
}

.pl-ii {
    background-color: #b52a1d;
    color: #f8f8f8;
}

.pl-sr .pl-cce {
    color: #63a35c;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pl-ml {
    color: #693a17;
}

.pl-mh,
.pl-mh .pl-en,
.pl-ms {
    color: #1d3e81;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pl-mq {
    color: #008080;
}

.pl-mi {
    color: #333;
    font-style: italic;
}

.pl-mb {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pl-md {
    background-color: #ffecec;
    color: #bd2c00;
}

.pl-mi1 {
    background-color: #eaffea;
    color: #55a532;
}

.pl-mdr {
    color: #795da3;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pl-mo {
    color: #1d3e81;
}

kbd {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    font: 11px Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Courier, monospace;
    line-height: 10px;
    color: #555;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-bottom-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #bbb;
}

.task-list-item {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.task-list-item + .task-list-item {
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.task-list-item input {
    margin: 0 0.35em 0.25em -0.6em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

:checked + .radio-label {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    border-color: #4078c0;
}

span.user-del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: inherit;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #f6f6f6;

    background-color: #959595;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 0px #ededed;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0px #ededed;

}
```